# Eyecup for Sony A7R II

Tags: sony, mirrorless, accessories

I'm looking for an eyecup for the Sony A7R II (possible round). I haven't found much available in the UK. Any options?

Comment: Did you try looking in online shops? If yes, which ones? None of them had eyecups for Sony A7R II ?

Comment: Nope what? Nope haven't searched online shops? Nope they had no eyecups whatsoever? Nope they had no round eyecups?

Comment: I have search major retail stores, and found nothing

Comment: You could also give amazon.co.uk a try ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ebay in Germany has this - 
http://www.ebay.de/itm/Rubber-Eyecup-Soft-for-Sony-A7-A7R-A7S-Cameras-GREAT-for-Video-Usage-/191728948175

Also in he USA BHPhoto 
- http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1165086-REG/hoodman_heyes_hoodeye_for_sony_a7_a7r_a7s_a711.html

Also maybe a diy might work for you if are good with your hands .

Or even a Chinese universal one - http://www.dx.com/p/universal-viewfinder-eyecup-for-dslr-slr-with-adapters-11206#.VpflmfnhC1s